# error-specific tryCatch

Tags: error-handling, r

R doesn't have classed errors, just (for the most part) `error` and `warning`, so determining if the error should be *caught* or *passed* is up to the programmer. From the python side, I've always appreciated the ability to catch specific errors and pass the rest on, as in an example from the py3 tutorial on [Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

```py
import sys
try:
    f = open('myfile.txt')
    s = f.readline()
    i = int(s.strip())
except OSError as err:
    print("OS error: {0}".format(err))
except ValueError:
    print("Could not convert data to an integer.")
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise
```

I'm familiar with [Adv-R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) and its discussions of `withCallingHandlers` and `tryCatch`, and below is an attempt to provide a single-point for selectively catching errors. Since R does not have classed errors as python does, I believe the "best" way to match specific errors is with regexps on the error message itself. While this is certainly imperfect, I think it's "good enough" (and perhaps the most flexible available).

```r
#' Pattern-matching tryCatch
#'
#' Catch only specific types of errors at the appropriate level.
#' Supports nested use, where errors not matched by inner calls will
#' be passed to outer calls that may (or may not) catch them
#' separately. If no matches found, the error is re-thrown.
#'
#' @param expr expression to be evaluated
#' @param ... named functions, where the name is the regular
#'   expression to match the error against, and the function accepts a
#'   single argument, the error
#' @param finally expression to be evaluated before returning or
#'   exiting
#' @param perl logical, should Perl-compatible regexps be used?
#' @param fixed logical, if 'TRUE', the pattern (name of each handler
#'   argument) is a string to be matched as is
#' @return if no errors, the return value from 'expr'; if an error is
#'   matched by one of the handlers, the return value from that
#'   function; if no matches, the error is propogated up
#' @export
#' @examples
#' 
#' tryCatchPatterns({
#'   tryCatchPatterns({
#'     stop("no-math-nearby, hello")
#'     99
#'   }, "^no-math" = function(e) { cat("in inner\n"); -1L })
#' }, "oops" = function(e) { cat("in outer\n"); -2L })
#' # in inner
#' # [1] -1
#'
#' tryCatchPatterns({
#'   tryCatchPatterns({
#'     stop("oops")
#'     99
#'   }, "^no-math" = function(e) { cat("in inner\n"); -1L })
#' }, "oops" = function(e) { cat("in outer\n"); -2L })
#' # in outer
#' # [1] -2
#'
#' tryCatchPatterns({
#'   tryCatchPatterns({
#'     stop("neither")
#'     99
#'   }, "^no-math" = function(e) { cat("in inner\n"); -1L })
#' }, "oops" = function(e) { cat("in outer\n"); -2L },
#'    "."    = function(e) { cat("in catch-all\n"); -3L })
#' # in catch-all
#' # [1] -3
#' 
#' \dontrun{
#' tryCatchPatterns({
#'   tryCatchPatterns({
#'     stop("neither")
#'     99
#'   }, "^no-math" = function(e) { cat("in inner\n"); -1L })
#' }, "oops" = function(e) { cat("in outer\n"); -2L })
#' # Error in eval(expr, envir = parentenv) : neither
#' }
#' 
tryCatchPatterns <- function(expr, ..., finally, perl = FALSE, fixed = FALSE) {
  parentenv <- parent.frame()
  handlers <- list(...)

  # ---------------------------------
  # check all handlers are correct
  if (length(handlers) > 0L &&
        (is.null(names(handlers)) || any(!nzchar(names(handlers)))))
    stop("all error handlers must be named")
  if (!all(sapply(handlers, is.function)))
    stop("all error handlers must be functions")

  # ---------------------------------
  # custom error-handler that references 'handlers'
  myerror <- function(e) {
    msg <- conditionMessage(e)
    handled <- FALSE
    for (hndlr in names(handlers)) {
      # can use ptn of "." for catch-all
      if (grepl(hndlr, msg, perl = perl, fixed = fixed)) {
        out <- handlers[[hndlr]](e)
        handled <- TRUE
        break
      }
    }
    if (handled) out else stop(e)
  }

  # ---------------------------------
  # quote some expressions to prevent too-early evaluation
  expr_q <- quote(eval(expr, envir = parentenv))
  finally_q <- if (!missing(finally)) quote(finally)
  tc_args <- list(error = myerror, finally = finally_q)

  # ---------------------------------
  # evaluate!
  do.call("tryCatch", c(list(expr_q), tc_args))
}
```

The intent is to be able to handle some errors perhaps differently (most likely in side-effect) but not necessarily catch *all* errors.

I'm particularly interested in these questions:

- **context of evaluating `expr`**: I believe `quote(eval(expr, envir = parentenv))` is sufficient for ensuring no surprises with namespace and search path, am I missing something?
- **context of the `error`**: it would be ideal if `traceback()` of a not-caught error did not originate in `myerror`, is there a better way to re-throw the error with (or closer to) the original stack?
- **similarly handle `warning`s**: I have another version of this that adds `warning`s in the same way, so it uses `withCallingHandlers` and conditional use of `invokeRestart("muffleWarning")`. The premise is that some warnings I don't care about (I might otherwise use `suppressWarnings`), some I want to log, and some indicate problems (that could also turn into errors with `options(warn=2)`). In developing shiny apps, I often use something like this (with a `logger::log_*` call instead of `cat`):

  ```r
  withCallingHandlers({
    warning("foo")
    99
  }, warning = function(w) {
    cat("caught:", conditionMessage(w), "\n")
    invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
  })
  # caught: foo 
  # [1] 99
  ```

  where it might be nice to "muffle" some warnings and not others. `warning` typically includes *where* the warning originated. Similar to the previous bullet, is there a way with `warning` to preserve (re-use) the original context?
- **assumptions**: am I making an egregious false assumption in the code?

Comment: You say “R doesn't have classed errors” … I’m unsure what you mean by that since you can write virtually the same code as the Python code in R: https://gist.github.com/klmr/ca110f867c059616ae88d76ceee9d47e

Comment: Great point (and big thanks for the demo code), but what errors in base R (and most packages, for that matter) class their exceptions like this?

Comment: None, unfortunately. I have no idea why this phenomenal condition system was written and never used. For what it’s worth I *do* use subclassed conditions in my own code.

Comment: Can you think of anything I'm mis-assuming or missing in the above function? I appreciate you looking at it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I think your evaluation context is correct; and yes, it’s convoluted. In particular it impacts your second point; and …
- … unfortunately I’m not aware of a way to improve this. You *can* manually modify the stack trace by editing the `base::.Traceback` variable (!). However, this must happen *after* `stop` is called so I don’t think it’s helpful here.
- Same answer.
- I think your assumptions are sound.

Two further points: you can slightly simplify your handler by using early exit:

```r
myerror <- function(e) {
  msg <- conditionMessage(e)
  for (hndlr in names(handlers)) {
    # can use ptn of "." for catch-all
    if (grepl(hndlr, msg, perl = perl, fixed = fixed)) {
      return(handlers[[hndlr]](e))
    }
  }
  stop(e)
}
```

And as you probably know there’s no need to quote `tryCatch` in the `do.call` call.

… an afterthought:

Something that simplifies the call stack slightly *and* circumvents the complex quoting of the expression is the following:

```r
call <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
tc_call <- call("tryCatch", expr = call$expr, error = myerror, finally = call$finally)
eval.parent(tc_call)
```

This seems to work.

Comment: I often quote the function in `do.call` in part due to https://rpubs.com/hadley/do-call, for better or worse. Your suggested `call <- ...` code looks simpler, I'll play with it some more. Many thanks!